# ffmpeg only set width

Tags: video, ffmpeg, width

I need to set width only, in ffmpeg.

I used the code below:

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_0361.mov -y -vcodec mpeg4 \
       -vf scale=480:-1 -r 15 \
       -b 64k -acodec libfaac -ac 1 -ar 8000 -ab 12200 \
       -flags bitexact IMG_0361.mp4
```

But it shows an error:

```
ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-vf'
```

Comment: Show the full console output of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Put your filter-chain between quotes, so the shell may not interpret the filter string as something else if it contains some special charaters.

I would change `-vf` to `-filter_complex` or `-filter:v`.
You could also turn the command to a single line command and try that way. (You didn't mentioned what shell you're using, so this could be a problem too).

Also, `-b` is ambigous and `-ab` is obsolete. For bitrate setting, use the `-b:<stream_specifier>` format.

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i IMG_0361.mov -codec:v mpeg4 -filter:v "scale=480:-1" -r 15 -b:v 64k -codec:a libfaac -ac 1 -ar 8000 -b:a 12200 -flags bitexact IMG_0361.mp4
```

Note that 64k is far too low for video even for that frame size, I'd suggest to increase it to 5-600k.